# Change rotation order of a matrix

Tags: export, mathematics, matrix

So, I am writing an exporter to another scenegraph format. Trouble is I suspect it has a different order of rotation (not 'XYZ').

So how do I change a Blender Matrix 3x3 or 4x4 into one that has same scaling (also if its negative), but the rotation has been applied in different order (say 'XZY')

This is my code so far, but it fails to preserve the scaling:

```
blenderMatrix = obj.matrix_basis * obj.matrix_parent_inverse
rotation = blenderMatrix.to_euler('XYZ') # Blenders Euler order
rotation.order = 'XZY'                   # export Euler order
exportMatrix = rotation.to_matrix().to_3x3()
# how do I here put the scale back into the exportMatrix?
```

Comment: I solved this, the problem was that the export matrix just had to be arranged in columns first, rows second.

Comment: Consider adding this as an answer to your own question. That will make it easier for others with the same or similar questions to find the solution.

Comment: Its not strictly an answer, it was more an conclusion that the question's assumptions were wrong in the first place.

Comment: @Amir sorry, nope.